# python: bugs on returning boolean and string together

Tags: python, return

I'm doing this programming question in python and I got some problems.
Question: Take a string of digits and split it, inserting * and   + operators (or concatenating some digits) so that the resulting expression evaluates to given number. If no solution, print "no solution found.

## Solution 1:

```
def findResult(s, goal):

    i = 1
    gg = False
    while gg ==False and i < len(s)+1:
        if int(s) == goal:
            gg = True
            return True

        num = int(s[0:i])
        if goal % num == 0:
            gg = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num) or findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num)
        else:
            gg = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num)
        i += 1
    
    return gg
    
ss = '12345'
goal = 691
print findResult(ss, goal)
```

when I tested this code, it will tell if the string can be calculated into the goal number (True or False). Then I wanted to return the calculating progress (1+2*345). I changed my code like this:

## Solution 2:

```
def findResult(s, goal, prog):
    i = 1
    gg = False
    while gg ==False and i < len(s)+1:

        if int(s) == goal:
            gg = True
            prog += s
            return (True,prog)
        else:
            num = int(s[0:i])
            if goal%num == 0:
                gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num,prog+"*"+str(num)) or findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+"+"+str(num))
            else:
                gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+"+"+str(num))
        i += 1
    
    return (gg,prog)
    
ss = '12345'
goal = 691
print findResult(ss, goal,"")
```

the output of this code is wrong. And what's I can't understand is that, the "gg" is changed from "True" to "False" as well. Can anyone tell me where my mistake is? And if possible, can you tell me a way to print the progress string? What's more, my programming style might be not clear. If you have any suggestions, I'm very glad to hear! Thanks!

Comment: whats the output of your second try ?

Comment: (False, '*1+2+3+4+5+45+34*5+345+23*4+5+45+234+5+2345+12+3*4+5+45+34*5+345+123*4+5+45+1234+5+12345')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version relies on the return value of `findResult()` returning *just* a boolean here:

```
gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num,prog+"*"+str(num)) or findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+"+"+str(num))
```

Note the `or` in that expression; `(False, somestring)` or `(True, somestring)` is *always True*! That's because a non-empty tuple is always considered to be true.

You'll need to split that out:

```
if goal%num == 0:
    gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num,prog+"*"+str(num))
    if not gg:
        gg, prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+"+"+str(num))
```

Note that it is not considered Pythonic to use `gg == False` to test for false values. Use `not gg` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried as what you said. It worked! And now my code works well!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num,prog+"*"+str(num)) or findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+"+"+str(num))
```

Here, you use `or` operator on tuples. However, nonempty tuples always evaluate to `True` in boolean context. You should write something like this instead:

```
gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num,prog+"*"+str(num))
if gg == False:
    gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+"+"+str(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to abacabadabacaba and Martijn Pieters! I got my code working. My code is now:

```
def findResult(s, goal, prog):
    i = 1
    gg = False
    while gg ==False and i < len(s)+1:

        if int(s) == goal:
            gg = True
            prog += s
            return (True,prog)

        num = int(s[0:i])
        if goal%num == 0:
            gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal / num,prog+str(num)+"*") 
            if gg == False:
                gg,prog =findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+str(num)+"+")
        else:
            gg,prog = findResult(s[i:len(s)], goal - num,prog+str(num)+"+")
        i += 1
    if gg == True:
        return (gg,prog)
    else:
        return (gg,"")

ss = '12345'
goal = 691
gg,result = findResult(ss, goal,"")
result += "=" + str(goal)
print result if gg else "No solution"
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: well, my method is wrong. But the problem of the posted code is solved. Thank you guys.